# How to link an accented domain name?

Tags: html, character-encoding

Since one or two years french accents are possible in domain name.

I want to add a link from my page toward this domain that contains one :

http://www.simulateur-prêt.fr

My page is encoded in UTF8 and here is my simple HTML link :

```
<a href="http://www.simulateur-prêt.fr"> FR </a>
```

This link on my page  (can be tested here http://www.theloancalculator.org) works fine wth Chrome.
But with Internet Explorer or Firefox it does not : they both try to open this weird address http://www.simulateur-prãat.fr/ that does not exist.

What is the right html code ? (I add that I don't want the user to end up on the target site with an url encoded address but with a properly accented french address).

BTW even stackoverflow seems to bug here as the link is not properly regognized by this editor.

Comment: Have you tried using the Hex code value for `ê` -  `<a href="http://www.simulateur-pr&#xEA;t.fr"> FR </a>` You can see a list of hex codes here - http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities

Comment: What is the character encoding of the page with the link? Does the server include a `charset` parameter in the `Content-Type:` header? Do you have a meta tag specifying the charset within the page itself? If you have both, are they conflicting?

Comment: Note that the UTF-8 sequence for `é` when viewed in Latin-1 becomes `Ã©` which is similar to what you see, but not quite the same thing. Is it possible that you copy/pasted the string incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Domains cannot contain non-ASCII letters. [Internationalised domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) are actually [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) encoded. In your case, the actual domain name is www.xn--simulateur-prt-2kb.fr.

Comment: I tried that html <a href="http://www.xn--simulateur-prt-2kb.fr"> FR </a>  but it does not change anything

Comment: with which browser does it work well for you ? are you talking about the puny encoded link or the link as it is now or both ?

Answer (score 0):

In FF 27, I see the correct URL both when I hover and on the site.

In Chrome 33, the link works but looks like this: http://www.xn--simulateur-prt-2kb.fr/

Comment: I changed the link to href="http://www.xn--simulateur-prt-2kb.fr" but still same issue. In FF 27, I see the correct url if I hover the link,  but if I click FF still tries to open http://www.simulateur-prãat.fr/

Answer (score -2):

Here is a lot of samples about international domain names (the extrem cases are for arabic and hebrew) but for french it still latin based language.

For example: the domain name http://créditautomobile.net would be rewritten as http://xn--crditautomobile-cnb.net/ and http://prêtautomobile.net would be http://xn--prtautomobile-qhb.net/

etc...